# Google Ads Conversion Id

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm new to Google Analytics. I succesfully made the migration from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4 by creating a GA4 property. The problem is the following. In the company that I work our website uses for Google Ads Conversion Tracking something called Google Conversion Id. But in every tutorial that I watched on the topic they used different steps. Steps with events and conversions in GA4 that were really confusing.

I tried creating an event and a conversion for our thank you page. I also tried the same via the google tag manager by creating a tag of type "Google Ads Conversion" for our thank you page. But in both cases without luck. The questions are the following.

Can I somehow use only the Google Conversion Id (without events and conversions, that most tutorial refers to)?.

Also is there any way to utilize the Google Tag Manager for the same purpose?

Any article or video will be appreciated!
Thank you all!